# Is there a risk with using Char(22) in code

Tags: c#, winforms

C# WinForms: If this a software people will be using in non-English languages too then will be a wrting a piece of code like this or is it fine? is there a better .NET way of wrting it?

```
if (eventArgs.KeyChar == (char)22)
```

**EDIT BY RB**: `char(22)` is [Synchronous Idle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-V), but is better known as "Ctrl+V" or "Paste". He's asking how to detect "Paste" in WinForms.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If your question's about the readability of your code then you could write it a lot cleaner. Which char is 22? I don't know and would have to look it up. I shouldn't need to do this therefore the code could be more readable. You could re-factor this in the following ways

- Simple use the char you need, ie. `eventArgs.KeyChar == 'e'`
- Use some enum, something like, `eventArgs.KeyChar == Keys.E`

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that with the `Keys` enumeration no SYN key is defined this should work.

But maybe you should declare somewhere a

```
public static readonly char SynChar = (char)22;
```